# Particles converted but no colors!

Tags: rendering, export, particles, color-management

when i convert my particles into a mesh (in this case grass) i don't get colors, even though the initial particles had materials and textures... even if i add them onto the new mesh nothing happens!! This is not because of the light because i've tried to play with it :P
This is what exactly happens: http://www37.zippyshare.com/v/93332560/file.html
And also if i export the black grass nothing gets shown in Unreal Engine (exported as fbx and obj)
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here might be because you're converting a hair type particle into a normal mesh which creates a mesh with no faces (only vertices and edges), therefore no color or texture that you try to apply will be displayed. Instead why don't you try to model a grass strand and then use the hair particle system to randomly distribute it over the plane.